# Building cuda and boost library with Makefile

Tags: c++, boost, cuda, makefile, nvcc

I have a `makefile`:

```
projectx: component1.obj \         
nvcc -O3 -arch=sm_20 -lcuda -o projectx component2.obj

component1.obj : component1.cu component1.h 
    nvcc -O3 -arch=sm_20 -c component1.cu
component2.obj : component2.cu cm.h component2.h
nvcc -O3 -arch=sm_20 -c component2.cu
```

`component1.cu` contains `#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>`
and when I'm trying to build it with `nmake` it tells me "Cannot open include file: 'boost/lambda/lambda.hpp'"

What should I do here? How to tell `nvcc` where to take this include files from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by putting `boost` 'include' files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-I` flag. E.g. `-I/opt/cuda-toolkit/include`

Comment: my boost library full path is: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_53_0
Please, could you tell me what I should do in Makefile exactly?

Comment: I tried to add BOOST_PATH=C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_53_0 and where is component1.obj  -I $(BOOST_PATH), but nvcc don't know what to do with it.